# WooComerce email template text change

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change text "Order" (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTJYo.png)) to something new without touching the actual ID of the order, but I can't find where or how to do it.

It would be awesome if there is a way to do it via `functions.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try Loco translate Plugin to translate the text.
here is the documentation: https://localise.biz/wordpress/plugin/beginners

It's a free plugin and east to use. Using this you can translate any text of any plugin

Answer (score 0):

Use this guide https://www.storeapps.org/customize-woocommerce-emails. There are several ways listed, but you probably want to try out the **Email Customizer for WooCommerce**-Plugin first. If you are not comfortable with the pricetag those plugins come, you can also to edit the framework under `wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/emails` (Search for "Order" and then simply replace it if thats already everything you want to modify)

Comment: It was actually inside /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-details.php

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/email-order-details.php